# How should "at some time" be tagged in Universal Dependencies framework?

Tags: syntax-trees, parts-of-speech, parsing, phrase-structure, dependency-grammar

I want to tag a sentence

> Jones was unemployed at some time before he graduated.

with [UD tags](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/u/dep/). I'm not sure how to tag *at some time*.

[Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) suggests the reading:

> case (time-6, at-4)
>
> det (time-6, some-5)
>
> nmod (unemployed-3, time-6)

But I'm a bit suspicious because it looks like it could be analysed as a **compound** or **mwe**.
Did ask uncle google but he couldn't help me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mwes are quite tricky, there's no widely accepted definition of what a mwe is so it depends on the framework used. "At some time", though, doesn't qualify as a mwe, it should be analysed as an ordinary PP.

Comment: I looked up similar phrases in the actual Universal Dependencies (version 2) data. I found "for some time" and "for quite some time", and both are analysed in the way you quote above.